# Convert HTML string to plain string Objective-C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, plaintext

I made a `UITableView` which each cell contains a `UILabel`. The input is some HTML string (like a website page source), eg from [Example Domain](http://example.org/):

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

but much larger, over 4000 characters.

I want to convert those HTML strings to plain string, for above example it will be:

> Example Domain
>
> This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior
>   coordination or asking for permission.
>
> More information...

and then display them in `UILabel`. Currently I'm using this way:

```
NSData *htmlData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
          initWithData:HTMLData
               options:@{
                   NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType
               }
    documentAttributes:nil
                 error:nil];
NSString *plainString = attrString.string;
```

This works fine, but the performance is very bad, which causes flickering when scrolling through the tableView. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: what about caching the string before reloading tableview ? you can generate the strings in background thread and then reuse them

Comment: Thanks, that's a good way, but my input for tableview is pretty complicated, so I prefer a way to convert the html string in-place instead of parsing all the data and cache them. I will try doing this though.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to do it on each cell appearance with high performance, because html is complicated and you have to go through the text to convert/replace/delete some parts of it, and if the html string is big , then problem is much bigger, especially for old devices, 

P.S. actually that function you wrote above, works better on the actual device than on the Simulator, you can try out yourself

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:

```
NSString * htmlString = ...;
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

UILabel * myLabel = [UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: Did you read my question? You use exactly the same method as I do :)

Comment: you look https://github.com/renegade78/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.h.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked out that but it seems the code is too old and isn't ARC compatible. And that's too much code for a simple thing like this :(